# Access external jar xml resource in web.xml (no spring)

Tags: java, eclipse, web, jar, web.xml

Is there a way to access a xml resource that resides in a jar from the web.xml?

```
    <init-param>
      <param-name>configFile</param-name>
      <param-value>config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
```

If config.xml is in an external jar how can I access it? (I don't use spring)

Comment: if the jar file is in your class path then can you try this                                 <param-value>classpath:config.xml</param-value>

Comment: the jar is correctly located in the lib folder of the web project. I've already tried with classpath but without success.